# No space left on device but disk not full

Tags: apt, partitioning, mount, disk-usage

```
root@-50:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G  1.7M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/md0        7.3T  7.0T     0 100% /
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/0

root@-50:~# sudo df -i /
Filesystem        Inodes IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/md0       244174848 99780 244075068    1% /
```

I use this as a backup server I mistakenly filled it up once but have since freed up space as you can see above but it still shows as 100% full. I've tried autoremove and autoclean also tried umount /tmp and it says not mounted. Does anyone know a solution to this, server is running fine but I need to update the software running on it and can't because of no space available. Thanks.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Linux filesystems reserve 5% of a partition's space for use only by the `root` user. 300GB is certainly quite a bit to set aside, but you can confirm this by using `dumpe2fs`:

```
dumpe2fs /dev/md0 | grep -i reserved
```

This will give you an output like:

```
dumpe2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Reserved block count:     5838835
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
  Reserved GDT blocks at 57-1080
  Reserved GDT blocks at 32825-33848
  Reserved GDT blocks at 98361-99384
  Reserved GDT blocks at 163897-164920
  Reserved GDT blocks at 229433-230456
  Reserved GDT blocks at 294969-295992
  Reserved GDT blocks at 819257-820280
  Reserved GDT blocks at 884793-885816
  Reserved GDT blocks at 1605689-1606712
  Reserved GDT blocks at 2654265-2655288
  Reserved GDT blocks at 4096057-4097080
  Reserved GDT blocks at 7962681-7963704
  Reserved GDT blocks at 11239481-11240504
  Reserved GDT blocks at 20480057-20481080
  Reserved GDT blocks at 23887929-23888952
  Reserved GDT blocks at 71663673-71664696
  Reserved GDT blocks at 78676025-78677048
  Reserved GDT blocks at 102400057-102401080
```

You can also change the amount of space reserved by using `tune2fs`:

```
tune2fs -m 0 /dev/md0
```

If this 5% reservation has already been set to 0 during some previous configuration work, it's possible that a process has opened a large file which has since been deleted. If this is the case, you will need to kill that process to free up the blocked storage space. You might be able to identify the process by using `lsof`. On Ubuntu, deleted yet open files are known to `lsof` and marked as `(deleted)` in the output.

You can check this with:

```
sudo lsof +L1
```

Which will give you something like:

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse file system /run/user/1000/doc
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND      PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NLINK     NODE NAME
none        1914     root  txt    REG    0,1    17032     0    43118 / (deleted)
pulseaudi   2185    jason    6u   REG    0,1 67108864     0    43740 /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)
Xorg        2269    jason   37u   REG    0,1        4     0    46738 /memfd:xshmfence (deleted)
Xorg        2269    jason   51u   REG    0,1        4     0   188039 /memfd:xshmfence (deleted)
Xorg        2269    jason   52u   REG    0,1        4     0  1559738 /memfd:xshmfence (deleted)
Xorg        2269    jason   53u   REG    0,1        4     0  1559752 /memfd:xshmfence (deleted)
Xorg        2269    jason   54u   REG    0,1        4     0  1538559 /memfd:xshmfence (deleted)
Xorg        2269    jason   55u   REG    0,1        4     0  1538346 /memfd:xshmfence (deleted)
Xorg        2269    jason   59u   REG    0,1        4     0   329944 /memfd:xshmfence (deleted)
Xorg        2269    jason   68u   REG    0,1        4     0   312483 /memfd:xshmfence (deleted)
Xorg        2269    jason   70u   REG    0,1        4     0   312485 /memfd:xshmfence (deleted)
Xorg        2269    jason   71u   REG    0,1        4     0   310664 /memfd:xshmfence (deleted)
Xorg        2269    jason   72u   REG    0,1        4     0   312648 /memfd:xshmfence (deleted)
...
```

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot this did the trick tune2fs -m 0 /dev/md0 and now its showing free space properly.