# Deleting files does not free up the space

Tags: disk-usage, disk, disk-management, df, du

I am getting `No space left on device` error when I run `git pull`.
This is output of my df command:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  155M  1.5G  10% /run
/dev/sda1       902G  864G     0 100% /
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
overlay         902G  864G     0 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/41f709d0b2adc00a148982b37f680c2580081da7647336f56d96ffc352ee6498/merged
overlay         902G  864G     0 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/33a0fa9916f59f39538d7412549fd92ced244764797c24ef1f58a17c3835cb40/merged
```

Notice the line:

```
/dev/sda1       902G  864G     0 100% /
```

Seems that disk is indeed full.

I deleted approx 2.5 GB of different ubuntu iso files from `/home/user/`. But it is still giving me same error.

I tried checking if those files are open with `sudo lsof | grep iso`. But the output contains hundreds of

```
lsof: no pwd entry for UID 999
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: Is something of those docker thingies running, possibly grabbing all free disk space as soon as there is some?

Comment: Yes docker is running. And there are a lot of `docker overlays` in the output of `df -h`.. But does that behave so weirdly!!! If yes, then whats the solution?

Comment: I'm not saying `that is the problem` - I'm saying; `The problem MIGHT be there.` I have no idea what to do about it as I don't know what you have there. So; a general piece of advice; think! Try by finding an answer to `What did you install and launch?`

Comment: If you have the default ext4 5% reservation, then you may need to delete significantly more than 2.5G (902G - 5% = 857G) before a non-privileged user can write stuff

Comment: @steeldriver can you please elaborate the concept a bit. What is 5% reservation? Do I have to delete  902 GB * 5% = 45GB of files? If yes why exactly?

Comment: @RajS see [No space left on device but disk not full](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313316/no-space-left-on-device-but-disk-not-full)

Comment: I tried finding files size greater than 90 MB using `find` command. Found bunch of personal backups done by someone on the server. Deleted 38 GBs. Able to do clone. Also I was not able to connect vscode to this machine using SSH. That too worked.